# getting data from database and arrangement like table

Tags: php, html, mysql, database

I have this code:

```
<?php
$dbhost = 'localhost';
$dbuser = 'MyUsername';
$dbpass = 'MyPassword';
$conn = mysql_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass);
if(! $conn )
{
  die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}
$sql = 'SELECT contactID, name, phone, email, choise, message
        FROM contact2';

mysql_select_db('nghiartc_contact');
$retval = mysql_query( $sql, $conn );
if(! $retval )
{
  die('Could not get data: ' . mysql_error());
}

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($retval, MYSQL_ASSOC))
{

    echo "<td>{$row['contactID']} </td><td>{$row['name']}</td><td>  {$row['phone']} </td><td>{$row['email']}</td> <td>{$row['choise']}</td> <td>{$row['message']}</td>";        
} 

mysql_close($conn);
?>
```

I'm trying to display the data from the database like this:

[image]

But right now I get:

[image]

Any idea how I need to modify the code, so I get my expected output?

Comment: You need to tell the browser where to place the table using `<table>` and what a row is with `<tr>`. If you do that your code will work fine :) Because the current output is just all the cells on a single row.

Comment: You can take a [tour] here and get a quick overview of this site.

Answer (score 0):

you are missing the table structure iteslf - try adding the `<table>` and `<tr>` tags. Then you can style it accordingly with borders etc.

```
echo"<table>";
//echo"<tr><th>...table header structure...</th></tr>";

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($retval, MYSQL_ASSOC))
{
    echo "<tr><td>{$row['contactID']} </td><td>{$row['name']}</td><td>  {$row['phone']} </td><td>{$row['email']}</td> <td>{$row['choise']}</td> <td>{$row['message']}</td></tr>";        
} 
echo"</table>";
```

Answer (score 0):

Please see that you haven't followed the proper HTML structure. You should be using  and  tags.

For example,

```
echo "<table border='1'>";

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($retval, MYSQL_ASSOC)) {
   echo "<tr>";
   echo "<td>{$row['contactID']} </td><td>{$row['name']}</td><td>  {$row['phone']} </td><td>{$row['email']}</td> <td>{$row['choise']}</td> <td>{$row['message']}</td>"; 
   echo "</tr>";      
} 
echo "</table>";
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: ha ha @Object Manipulator - already posted that - just got in before you. :))

Comment: Good job, mate. Haha. :)

Answer (score 0):

You are missing `table` tags to start your table and `tr` tags for each row of data, so you would have to modify your while loop to this:

```
echo "<table>";
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($retval, MYSQL_ASSOC))
{

    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td>{$row['contactID']}</td>
          <td>{$row['name']}</td>
          <td>{$row['phone']}</td>
          <td>{$row['email']}</td>
          <td>{$row['choise']}</td>
          <td>{$row['message']}</td>";    
    echo "</tr>";    
} 
echo "</table>";
```

---

[**But please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12859942). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). See the [**red box**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-connect.php)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli).

So I would highly recommend to change your code to PDO, read more in the manual, an as example:

```
<?php

    $dbhost = 'localhost';
    $dbuser = 'nghiartc_contact';
    $dbpass = 'ZP5IEVeyKx';

    try {

        $dbh = new PDO("mysql:host=$dbhost;dbname=nghiartc_contact", $dbuser, $dbpass);
        $dbh->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

        $result = $dbh->query("SELECT contactID, name, phone, email, choise, message FROM contact2");

    } catch(PDOException $e) {
        echo $e->getMessage();
    }


    echo "<table>";
    foreach($result->fetchAll() as $row){
        echo "<tr>";
            echo "<td>" . $row["contactID"] . "</td>";
            echo "<td>" . $row["name"] . "</td>";
            echo "<td>" . $row["phone"] . "</td>";
            echo "<td>" . $row["email"] . "</td>";
            echo "<td>" . $row["choise"] . "</td>";
            echo "<td>" . $row["message"] . "</td>";
        echo "</tr>";
    }
    echo "</table>";

    $dbh = NULL;

?>
```

Comment: i tried this code but didnt work, i got er "SQLSTATE[3D000]: Invalid catalog name: 1046 No database selected", can you fix it?. and i have one ques so how to insert theme or style for table on this code. Thnks!

Comment: @phạmngọcchuyển Had a typo in my code `database` and `dbname`, should work now.

Comment: also a typo here: echo "</talbe>"; - should be  echo "</table>";